# LinkageError: loader constraints violated when linking javax/xml/namespace/QName in Websphere6.1 using resteasy

Tags: web-services, websphere

I am getting this error when making a web services call. I couldn't figure out a workround for this. ANy help is greatly appreciated.

related library I have is:
axis-1.3.jar
axis-jaxrpc-1.3.jar
axis-saaj-1.3.jar
axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar

jaxb-api-2.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.8.jar
jaxen-1.1-beta-9.jar
jaxrs-api-1.0-beta-9.jar

In websphere 61 admin setting is the following:
Enterprise Application
   -> WAR Classloader Mode : PARENT_LAST
 * Web Module :
   -> ClassLoader Mode :  application_FIRST

Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraints violated when linking javax/xml/namespace/QName class
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:224)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:61)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:127)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:79)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.(ModelBuilder.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:87)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:432)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.(JAXBContextImpl.java:297)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:139)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:211)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:372)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBContextWrapper.(JAXBContextWrapper.java:74)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBContextWrapper.(JAXBContextWrapper.java:99)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.XmlJAXBContextFinder.createContextObject(XmlJAXBContextFinder.java:48)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBContextFinder.createContext(AbstractJAXBContextFinder.java:114)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.XmlJAXBContextFinder.findCachedContext(XmlJAXBContextFinder.java:39)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.findJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:49)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:112)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.writeTo(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:88)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.MessageBodyParameterMarshaller$ClientRequestEntity.(MessageBodyParameterMarshaller.java:88)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.MessageBodyParameterMarshaller.buildRequest(MessageBodyParameterMarshaller.java:51)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:197)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:46)
        at $Proxy51.updateAccount(Unknown Source)
        at com.amg.brides.wedsimple.client.WedSimpleClientImpl.updateAccount(WedSimpleClientImpl.java:72)
        at com.amg.brides.wedsimple.web.WedSimpleUpdateAccountEvent.invokeClient(WedSimpleUpdateAccountEvent.java:24)
        at com.amg.brides.wedsimple.web.AbstractWedSimpleAccountEvent.execute(AbstractWedSimpleAccountEvent.java:35)
        at com.amg.brides.util.WebEventProcessor.processEvents(WebEventProcessor.java:29)

Answer (score 6):

The basic problem is that you're loading one or more class files related to xml from an incorrect jar. Your application server does not permit you to change these libraries, because it has already loaded most of the parser from a different implementation. I tried to inspect the content of the jar files looking for javax/xml/namespace but stopped halfway. If you find it there's a good chance you can get one without the offending classes. People have been known to manually remove such files from external jars.

You can probably turn on som vm options to log classloading while the container is running. This is the java -verbose:class option.

I'm sorry I cant pinpoint the exact problem ;)

Answer (score 4):

**Possible solution (worked for me)**

In Websphere 7 I have the same problem with axis 1.3 and 1.4
I have resolved removing QName.class from axis-jaxrpc-1.3.jar in WEB_INF\lib

This because QName.class was already present in other jar file.